# Coercivity of an integral operator in $L^2$-norm

Tags: functional-analysis, coercive

Let us consider the integral operator $T:L^2(0,1)\to [0,\infty)$ such that for all $k\in L^2(0,1)$,
$$
T(k)=\int_0^1 k_t^2e^{-2 \int_0^t k_s d s}  d t.
$$

Is the operator $T$   coercive in the $L^2$ sense, i.e.,
$ T(k)\to \infty$ as $|k|_{L^2}\to \infty$?

---

Let us assume without loss of generality that $k_t\ge 0$ for all $t$.
If we employ the rough estimate:
$$
T(k)\ge \int_0^1 k_t^2 d t e^{-\int_0^1 2k_s\, d s}\ge |k|^2_{L^2} e^{-2|k|_{L^2}},
$$
then it  seems to indicate that the functional is not coercive, as $|k|_{L^2} \exp(- 2|k|_{L^2})$   tends to zero as $|k|_{L^2}\to \infty$.

However, the above inequality is a quite poor lower bound. In fact, if we consider the sequence of functions $(k^n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ where for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$,
$k^n=\alpha_n/2$ on $[0,1/n]$ and zero otherwise, then $|k^n|^2_{L^2}=\alpha_n^2//4n$, and a direct computation shows that
$$
T(k^n)\sim \alpha_n (1-e^{-\alpha_n/n}), \quad n\in \mathbb{N},
$$
and hence $\lim_{n\to \infty}\alpha_n^2/n=\infty$ indeed implies
$\lim_{n\to \infty} T(k^n) = \infty$.

---

I feel I am closer to prove that the claim is false. Consider $k_t=(1-t)^{-1}$ for all $t\in (0,1)$. Note that $k\not \in L^1(0,1)$.
A direct computation shows that
$ \int_0^t k_s d s =-\ln (1-t)$ and hence
$$
T(k)=\int_0^1 (1-t)^{-2}e^{2\ln (1-t)}  d t=1.
$$
So if I could find a sequence of $(k^n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$   approaching $k$ with $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} T(k^n)<\infty$ then I may get a counterexample.

Comment: By $k_s$ do you mean $k(s)$? In that case is $k_s^2$ supposed to be $k_t^2$ as the integration variable is $t$?

Comment: @user23571113 Thank you for pointing out my typo. I have corrected the error in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is false. Here is a counterexample. For each $\epsilon>0$, consider $k^\epsilon_t=(1+\epsilon-t)^{-1}$ for all $t\in (0,1)$. Note that $k^\epsilon  \in L^2(0,1)$, with $\int_0^1 (k^\epsilon_t)^2 d t=\frac{1}{\epsilon(1+\epsilon)}$. In particular $|k^\epsilon|_{L^2}\to \infty$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.

A direct computation shows that
$ \int_0^t k^\epsilon_s d s =\ln(1+\epsilon)-\ln (1+\epsilon-t)$ and hence
$$
T(k^\epsilon)=\int_0^1 (1+\epsilon-t)^{-2}e^{2(\ln (1+\epsilon-t)-\ln(1+\epsilon))}  d t=\frac{1}{(1+\epsilon)^2}.
$$
So $T(k^\epsilon)$ remains finite as $\epsilon \to 0$.  A similar conterexample has been given in Proposition 2.4 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.00617.pdf).